# Como Capturar esse array

Tags: json, array

Eu estou tentando fazer uma *API*.

**Esse é o meu código:**

```
require('conexao/conexao.php');


$jsonObj= array();



$query="SELECT * FROM filmes";
$sql = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{ 
    $row[] = $data;
    header("Content-type:application/json");            
    array_push($jsonObj,$row);

}
```

Estou tentando pegar os dados da *API* com o código abaixo, porém não me retorna nada:

```
$url = "http://fimhd.com.br/api.php";
$captura = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($captura);

var_dump($json);
```

Answer (score 3):

É necessário que você imprima o conteúdo na tela. Para isso você terá que utilizar duas funções: [**json_encode**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) e [**echo**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php).

O `array_push` servirá apenas para adicionar o resultado da variável `$row` no *array* `$jsonObj`, mas ele não é responsável pela impressão.

Segue código de exemplo.

```
<?php

require('conexao/conexao.php');

$jsonObj= array();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filmes") or die(mysql_error());

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{ 
    $row[] = $data;
    array_push($jsonObj,$row);
}

header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($jsonObj);
```

O [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) servirá para transformar o array `$jsonObj` para uma *string* no formato `json` e o [echo](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php) será para imprimir essa *string* na tela.

Comment: Obrigado Cara, funcionou aqui :D